# insanely slow loading of webpage

Tags: performance, apache

So I left my webapp alone for a bit...and after a few months I come back to some HORRIBLE performance. Note I'm using Django to serve up a webapp and also accept API requests (all JSON). Hosted on AWS EC2 instance (so I doubt network perf is the problem here)

[image]

I'm talking like SECONDS slow. For small css and js files. The site is coinsniff.com

I honestly can't find the culprit of the insane slowdown (note that before, it would consistently fully load UNDER 200ms.)

What I've tried so far:

- ping coinsniff (all looks clean)

  PING coinsniff.com (184.168.221.26): 56 data bytes
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=41.419 ms
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=41.714 ms
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=43.386 ms
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=46.929 ms
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=45.765 ms
  64 bytes from 184.168.221.26: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=44.320 ms
- Purge uninstall apache2 and fresh reinstall (looks fine, still looks slow)
- apt-get update (nothing)
- Clean out mysql table and check mysql performance (shouldn't be a big deal)
- Check htop and top (everything looks fine, no insane spikes and avg CPU is VERY low)
- Try to open up a new EC2 instance with the same image (same exact performance problems)
- stop all user started background tasks (same problems...)
- Restart apache2, restart server, restart EVERYTHING (no luck)
- update Django, pip upgrade everything in virtualenv (still nothing)
- Checked apache logs AND background task logs, nothing out of the ordinary

I'm at a loss as to what to investigate. I can't imagine what would take some simple js and css. Please help? :)

Comment: What ever the issue is it seems that to look at django would be to bark up the wrong tree. Clearly the problem is with the delivery of static content. If you remove the django tag you will probably get more apache experts looking at this.

Comment: did as you suggested. except...when i reset apache and had it going towards the default/sample index.html, it served instantly? so maybe it isn't an apache problem? but it maybe could be a wsgi.py problem?

Comment: If that is the case you have misconfigured your apache, it's not delivering the statics directly as it should.